# Jinja 2 markups showing when i try to use apache with a flask python coded webpage

Tags: python, apache, flask

The website is accessible by other computers by inputting the ip address of the host computer.
However, the jinja2 markups are shown.
[Jinja2 markups image](http://i60.tinypic.com/2hf44nd.png)

And the links which use url_for do not work either.
[Non-working url image](http://i60.tinypic.com/10rk56h.png)

What is the issue here?
Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flask / jinja is not a "server page" type of technology like PHP, so jinja templates (which by themselves know nothing about flask - jinja can be used from any Python code) won't be automagically "interpreted". You have to configure your apache server to serve content from flask as documented here : http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/